# Several Navigation Controllers in an app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.2

I have an app with `navigation controller`, but my app also has a simple separate view which is not a `navigation controller` part. And what I want to do is to add a brand new `navigation controller` to this view.
For my first `navigation controller` I used this code in my **AppDelegate**:

```
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController new]   initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

    navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewController1];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

But which code I should use, if I want to create a new `Navigation Controller` ?

Thanks !

**UPDATE:**

So, I made some pictures:

One the first pic there is a `navigation controller` (which is declared in AppDelegate). And It contains an info button. Then, when we press the button we move to another view (pic 2). And its just a `navigation bar` in this view, not an `navigation controller`. I wanna add a navigation controller, not a navigation bar in this view, so users will be able to use `UITableView` easily

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using UITabBarController? I can't completely understand your design. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, I don't use UITabBarController. I just wanna add a new navigation controller in a view. And this view is not a part of my first navigation controller. And I can't use the code which I used in the AppDelegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would need to know a little more about your intended view hierarchy, and application flow.  But in the code you're posting, I'm not sure what is going on.  Why not just:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

That said, you would create other `UINavigationController`s exactly the same way.

**Update:**

When you press the info button on the first view, you could present the navigation controller modally I think.

```
- (IBAction)infoButtonAction:(id)sender;
{
    //  InfoTableViewController is the controller with Instructions, Contact, and something else
    //  my Russian isn't so good.
    InfoTableViewController *tableController = [[InfoTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableController];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;    //  or whatever
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

Note that I'm not dealing with memory management because I don't know if this is ARC or not.  Is that how it should behave?

Comment: Thanks!
Yeah, in my app there is a nav. controller which is declared in AppDelegate. So it works well but I also have some views, which are don't parts of this navigation bar. And I want to add a new navigation controller in one of thee views, so it will be two navigation controllers in the whole app. I tried code above, but when I write **self** in the .m file, xcode doesn't offer to me to choose **window** after or something, so it doesn't work.
Sorry for complexity.

Comment: Where do these three other views exist in the view hierarchy?  Perhaps we could be of more help to you with a more complete description of that.  As @Canopus suggested, I also get the sense that a `UITabBarController` design sounds like what you want - but hard to say.

Comment: Perfect! It works very well, I just changed some things, but I get the idea and now its how I was wanted to be :)
Thank you very much!